# Using SOAP V2, I encounter some conflict

Tags: soap, php-5.4, ce-1.9.1.0, nvp-gateway-error, php-5.2.x.x

A: http://[magento site]/api/v2_soap/index/ - error 500

B: http://[magento site]/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/ - Working

Formerly the A is working to my old site which have 5.5 PHP version and now I migrated to another site which have 5.2 PHP version which cause the A: getting error 500 and now I'm using the B: which is working now. My concern is that there is a 3rd party connecting to the site which is using the A: and now there getting issue on getting any output from the site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 1.9.1.0 is not compatible with PHP 5.2.

You can read the system requirements [here](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements). Since this was caused after migrating I'm fairly sure this will be the cause of the issues.

I would advice to upgrade to at least PHP 5.4